# BST code stops working after deleting the int in main

Tags: c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

So, I was trying to write a Binary tree code with only inserting, and it was working but after I delete some useless `int` it stops working for some reason. Can anyone tell me why

So, here is my code, and it's working properly. But when I delete the `int i=3;` in `int main` it stops working. Why is that? Btw `int i=3;` is just a random number it still works if I change it to some other number

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 

struct Treenode{ 
    int data; 
    struct node*left; 
    struct node*right; 
}; 
typedef struct Treenode Treenode;


struct Treenode* CreateTree(struct Treenode** tree, int num) { 
 
    Treenode*temp = NULL;
    if(!(*tree))
    {
        temp = (Treenode*)malloc(sizeof(Treenode));
        temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
        temp->data = num;
        *tree = temp;
        return;
    }

    if(num < (*tree)->data){
        CreateTree(&(*tree)->left, num);
    }
    else if(num > (*tree)->data){
        CreateTree(&(*tree)->right, num);
    }
    
}

void inorder(struct Treenode* root)
{
    if (root != NULL) {
        inorder(root->left);
        printf("%d \n", root->data);
        inorder(root->right);
    }
}

int main(){
    int i = 3;
    //creating tree
    Treenode*root;
    
    
    CreateTree(&root, 1);
    CreateTree(&root, 2);
    CreateTree(&root, 3);
    CreateTree(&root, 4);
    CreateTree(&root, 5);
    CreateTree(&root, 6);

    inorder(root);
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `CreateTree` claims to return a value, but doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The non-static local variable `Treenode *root;` is not initialized, so its initial value is indeterminate. Using such indeterminate value may cause some trouble.

Initialize the variable like `Treenode *root = NULL;` to fix the issue.

Also note that casting results of `malloc()` family is [considered as a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).